# Configuring a separate audio input and output devices on RPi 2 Jessie

Tags: usb, audio, output

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 running Jessie as a device that takes basic audio input, processes it, and produces an audio output.

The speaker is plugged into the headphone jack. I want to assign the RPi audio output to it. At the same time I have a USB microphone which I want to use as an input device.

I set the audio output using `raspi-config`, but I don't know how to assign the audio input to a USB device without having to set the audio output to the USB device.

If this is helpful, I also own a USB audio dongle, but I can't plug the microphone into it.